# Errno(0) when failing to insert with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an error when inserting data into a table with php using prepared statements, I am stuck cuz it gives me errno(0), I dont know what that error is, can you help me please?. Thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../conexion.php';

$nombre        = $_POST['Nombre'];
$apellido      = $_POST['Apellido'];
$mail          = $_POST['Mail'];
$telefono      = $_POST['Telefono'];
$ultimaventa   = $_POST['Numeroventa'];
$totalcomprado = 0;
$ultimomonto   = $_POST['Total'];
if($cons = $mysqli->prepare("select 1 from clientes WHERE Mail=?"));
$cons->bind_param('s',$mail);
$cons->execute();
$cons->store_result();

$existe=$cons->num_rows > 0;

if ($existe) {
    $totalcomprado=totalcomprado+$ultimomonto;
    if(!($cons=$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE clientes SET   nombre=?,apellido=?,Mail=?,telefono=?,ultimaventa=?,ultimomonto=?,totalcomprado= ? WHERE Mail=?"))){
        echo "fallo en la preparacion de la consulta:(".$mysqli->errno.")" .$mysqli->error;
    }
    $cons->bind_param('sssssiis',$nombre,$apellido,$mail,$telefono,$ultimaventa,$totalcomprado,$mail);
    if(!($cons->execute())){
        echo "fallo ejecutando la consulta:(".$mysqli->errno.")" .$mysqli->error;
    }
    $cons->close;

} else {
    $totalcomprado=$ultimomonto;
    if(!($cons=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT into clientes id,nombre,apellido,Mail,telefono,ultimaventa,ultimomonto,totalcomprado values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))){
        echo "fallo en la preparacion de la consulta:(".$mysqli->errno.")" .$mysqli->error;
    }
    $cons->bind_param('sssssis',$nombre,$apellido,$mail,$telefono,$ultimaventa,$totalcomprado);
    if(!($cons->execute())){
        echo "fallo ejecutando la consulta:(".$mysqli->errno.")" .$mysqli->error;

    }
}
```

Ps.: The data types to insert are ok, the only one Integer is "ultimomonto"

This is the error:

> fallo en la preparacion de la consulta:(0)
>   ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\mumushop\compras\verificar.php on line 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses arount the column names in the `INSERT` statement:

```
    if(!($cons=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT into clientes (id,nombre,apellido,Mail,telefono,ultimaventa,ultimomonto,totalcomprado) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))){
```

There's another problem that isn't related to the error:

```
if($cons = $mysqli->prepare("select 1 from clientes WHERE Mail=?"));
```

The `;` ends this `if` statement, so you're not using it to execute anything based on whether this is successful. I think you want all the rest of the code to be inside this, so it should be:

```
if($cons = $mysqli->prepare("select 1 from clientes WHERE Mail=?")) {
    $cons->bind_param('s',$mail);
    $cons->execute();
    $cons->store_result();

    $existe=$cons->num_rows > 0;

    if ($existe) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

The undefined constant error is coming from this line:

```
$totalcomprado=totalcomprado+$ultimomonto;
```

You're missing the `$` before `totalcomprado`, it should be:

```
$totalcomprado=$totalcomprado+$ultimomonto;
```

or you can write it as:

```
$totalcomprado += $ultimomonto;
```

Comment: Ok, thats working, but now when I enter the UPDATE part it says:Notice: Use of undefined constant totalcomprado - assumed 'totalcomprado' in C:\wamp\www\mumushop\compras\verificar.php on line 20

Comment: where totalcomprado is a column in the table

Comment: You're missing a `$` before a variable.

Comment: cuz I am not intendig to refer to the variable wich value is 0, i am refering to the value in the column of my table

Comment: You can't refer to columns of a table like that. You have to use `$cons->bind_result($variable1, $variable1, ...)` to set variables that get the column values, and then use `$cons->fetch()` to fetch a row of results.

Comment: But you don't have any `SELECT` queries that return columns of your table.

Comment: Cant I use it with the mysqli->prepare("select 1 from clientes WHERE Mail=?")?? or I have to query again?

Comment: No. That just returns `1`, not any table columns.

Comment: You need something like `select totalcomprado FROM clientes WHERE Mail=?`